# Django Rest Auth - Key error on Email Confirmation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to setup email verification in DRF using rest-auth.
The registration works correctly and the verification email is sent. However, when going to the verification link I receive a key error.

What I understand is that means that this verification key doesn't exist, but I don't understand how to fix that given that the registration process was supposedly a success?

I have the following paths in my urls.py:

```
path('', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
path('', include('rest_auth.urls')),
path('registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
path('registration/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='account_signup'),
re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),
re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
```

The following settings in my settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

And this is a screenshot of the error I am getting:

[Key error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjlut.png)

Comment: Can you try re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email')

Comment: I did try that. It's what I originally had, was just trying out using pk as per another online source. Forgot to add the right one in the post. It's updated now. It still doesn't work tho

Comment: hello @Amrsaeed please did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @OpeyemiOdedeyi Sorry, never found a solution for this part.

Comment: I was able to find a solution, do you mind I share? but a summary from what I learned is that, 1) when using Django-rest-auth, we NEVER DIRECTLY use Django-all auth, that is if we are going for a full rest API endpoint throughout our page     2) I also learned from the FAQ page on the documentation that this problem we are facing is expected and that to verify the users without error, we would have to solve that somehow with our own view, which is where I found a solution on GitHub

Answer (score 2):

how I solved this issue

I had to create a view to verify the email my self, also note that I have a custom user model which is the goal when working on a big project

views.py

```
from rest_auth.registration.views import RegisterView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from allauth.account.models import EmailConfirmation, EmailConfirmationHMAC
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class ConfirmEmailView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = confirmation = self.get_object()
        confirmation.confirm(self.request)
        # A React Router Route will handle the failure scenario
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/api/rest-auth/login/')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        key = self.kwargs['key']
        email_confirmation = EmailConfirmationHMAC.from_key(key)
        if not email_confirmation:
            if queryset is None:
                queryset = self.get_queryset()
            try:
                email_confirmation = queryset.get(key=key.lower())
            except EmailConfirmation.DoesNotExist:
                # A React Router Route will handle the failure scenario
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/failure/')
        return email_confirmation

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = EmailConfirmation.objects.all_valid()
        qs = qs.select_related("email_address__user")
        return qs
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_auth.registration.views import VerifyEmailView, RegisterView
from rest_auth.views import PasswordResetView, PasswordResetConfirmView
from users.api.views import ConfirmEmailView


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('api/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url('api/account/', include('users.api.urls')),
    url('api/rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),



    url(r'^verify-email/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', ConfirmEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),

    url(r'^rest-auth/password/reset/$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',

    'users',
]

SITE_ID = 1

# to use old_password when setting a new password
OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = True
# to keep the user logged in after password change
LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE = False

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True

# UNSURE
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400 # 1 day in seconds
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ='/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile'
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'youremail@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

NOTE: I noticed that the URLs have to be in that order to work for me when they weren't in that order it didn't work for me. I also noticed that reset passwords give issues too so the fix is also there. I hope this solves your problem. and in case you post a reply and I haven't responded, just mail me at 'opeyemiodedeyi@gmail.com'

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old post but I just wanna share what I used as a solution in hopes that it helps someone else experiencing a similar issue.

```
# import the confirm_email views from allauth.accounts.views
from allauth.account.views import confirm_email

# once that's done, change your url view portion from 
# VerifyEmailView.as_view() to the newly imported view
re_path(r"^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$", confirm_email,
        name="account_confirm_email"),
```

Comment: I don't think it is what he was trying to achieve, he was trying to make a rest framework, by importing confirm_email which is from all auth, it takes it away from being a rest framework